# Entanglement entropy and depth

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, entanglement, information-theory, entropy

I wanted to verify two intuitions about the entanglement entropy of quantum states.

Consider an $n$ qubit quantum state, prepared by a depth $d$ circuit acting on $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$ and a bipartition of the state into two systems, $A$ and $B$. Let the boundary between $A$ and $B$ be of size $M$.

The von Neumann entanglement entropy of the reduced density matrix, for each bipartition, should be at most $Md$. This is because there can be at most $Md$ entangling gates across the bipartition ($M$ gates for each time-step), and each gate would increase the entanglement entropy by at most $1$.

Hence, for all 1D circuits of depth $d$, where $M$ is a constant, the entanglement entropy is at most a constant times $d$.

Are these intuitions correct?

---

The source of the confusion is [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.12814) paper, where on page 19, they exhibit a $\text{poly}\log$ depth 1D circuit with entropy ~$n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true that the increase in von Neumann entropy of entanglement between the two partitions due to a single cross-partition two-qubit gate is at most one. See below for an example where the increase is two. However, we can use log Schmidt rank to justify a different asymptotically linear upper bound.

### Product states

A two-qubit gate cannot produce more than one ebit of entanglement when applied to a product state. This follows from Schmidt decomposition and the fact that the Hilbert space of one qubit is two-dimensional.

### Counterexample

However, the argument fails when the qubits to which the gate is applied have preexisting entanglement with other qubits. For example, consider four qubits $A_1A_2B_1B_2$ in the state

$$
|\psi_0\rangle = \frac12(|0_{A_1}0_{A_2}\rangle+|1_{A_1}1_{A_2}\rangle)\otimes(|0_{B_1}0_{B_2}\rangle+|1_{B_1}1_{B_2}\rangle).\tag1
$$

Clearly, the initial entanglement entropy between the partition $A=A_1A_2$ and $B=B_1B_2$ is zero. However, following a single SWAP gate applied to qubits $A_2$ and $B_1$, we get

$$
|\psi_1\rangle = \frac12(|0_{A_1}0_{B_1}\rangle+|1_{A_1}1_{B_1}\rangle)\otimes(|0_{A_2}0_{B_2}\rangle+|1_{A_2}1_{B_2}\rangle)\tag2
$$

with the reduced state of partition $A$

$$
\rho=\mathrm{tr}_{B}(|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|)=\frac{I_2}{2}\otimes\frac{I_2}{2}=\frac{I_4}{4}\tag3
$$

and entanglement entropy $S(\rho)=2$.

### Schmidt rank

By Schmidt decomposition, a state $|\phi\rangle$ of partitions $A$ and $B$ can be written as

$$
|\phi\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i|i_A\rangle|i_B\rangle\tag4
$$

where $\lambda_i>0$ are Schmidt coefficients and $|i_X\rangle$ are orthonormal states of partition $X=A,B$. The number $m$, often denoted by $\mathrm{Sch}(|\phi\rangle)$ and called the Schmidt rank of the bipartite state $|\phi\rangle$, is another important measure of entanglement.

For any $m$ positive real numbers $s_1, \dots, s_m$ summing to $1$, the Shannon entropy $H(s_1,\dots,s_m)\le\log m$. Therefore, the logarithm of the Schmidt rank provides an upper bound on von Neumann entropy

$$
S(\mathrm{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)) \le \log\mathrm{Sch}(|\psi\rangle)\tag5
$$

for any pure bipartite state $|\psi\rangle$.

### Increase in log Schmidt rank due to one gate

We can derive an upper bound on the increase in log Schmidt rank due to a single two-qubit cross-partition gate. Suppose the gate $U$ has operator Schmidt rank $r$, i.e. can be written as

$$
U=\sum_{j=1}^rR_j\otimes S_j\tag6
$$

for some single-qubit operators $R_j$ and $S_j$ acting on a qubit in partition $A$ and $B$, respectively and orthogonal with respect to Hilbert-Schmidt inner product (see e.g. $6.4.2$ in [Nielsen's PhD thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0011036) or [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0208077) for more details on operator variant of Schmidt decomposition). Then $U|\phi\rangle$ may be written as

$$
\begin{align}
|\phi'\rangle=U|\phi\rangle&=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^r\lambda_iR_j|i\rangle S_j|i'\rangle \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{mr}\mu_k|k''\rangle|k'''\rangle
\end{align}\tag7
$$

so$^1$ $|\phi'\rangle$ has Schmidt rank at most $mr$.

Now, $R_j$ and $S_j$ belong to the complex vector space of operators on $\mathbb{C}^2$ which is four dimensional. Therefore, for a two-qubit gate $r\le 4$. We conclude that a two qubit gate can increase the log Schmidt rank by at most two.

### Linear bound on von Neumann entropy

Therefore, by $(5)$ the final von Neumann entropy $S_f$ of entanglement between the two partitions after running a circuit with $Md$ cross-partition two-qubit gates can be bounded above as

$$
S_f\le 2Md.\tag8
$$

Even though $(8)$ is not as tight as $Md$, it is still asymptotically linear.

---

<sup>$^1$ Every representation of a bipartite state $|\psi\rangle$ as a sum of product states has at least $\mathrm{Sch}(|\psi\rangle)$ terms. See e.g. Problem $2.2$ on page $117$ in Nielsen & Chuang.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, as always, for a fantastic answer! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Thank you for the kind words and an interesting question! Note that it may be possible to prove the tighter bound $Md$ since the input is a product state. I don't know how to do this rigorously right now, though. A special case where the above arguments imply $S_f\le Md$ occurs if the boundary qubits spend half of the time interacting with neighbors across the boundary and half the time interacting with neighbors in their home partition.